# How can I use my password hash for Winrm in ansible?

Tags: hash, ansible, winrm

I'm trying to use a winrm connection with Ansible but it doesn't work with the hash of my admin's password.

My file with my variables for winrm connection :

```
ansible_user: administrator

ansible_password: $5$3Q6y9t99hrJhXisv$CnNhma8CjVLJr5Noz9066v3YFsx3lGVqiGyMSZ0CP73

ansible_connection: winrm

ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore

ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm

ansible_winrm_port: 5985
```

I would like to know what I need to do for resolve it.

Comment: "_... but it doesn't work with the hash of my admin's password._", right, this is the expected behavior since the value for `ansible_password` is meant to be the password and not the hash of the password (and which is obviously something different). In other words `password != hash`.

Comment: "_I would like to know what I need to do for resolve it._" you may proceed further with reading about [Protecting sensitive variables with `ansible-vault`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/first_inventory.html#protecting-sensitive-variables-with-ansible-vault).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace my hash by my plain-text password and after I use ansible-vault for encrypt my file with the following command

```
ansible-vault encrypt group_vars/win.yaml
```

Vault ask me a new password for use this file and after I just need to add `--ask-vault-pass` at the end of my playbook command